# update tbl_1 set tbl_1.valueA = tbl2.valueB when tbl_2.valueC is equal to tbl_1valueD

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

As the title indicates - I'm trying to update a table.value with another table.value based on a common value in the 2 tables (but not same column names)

First I delete any duplicate records in the source table.
And count the remaining rows - that total is 93.

```
Select rowid, xfmid_value from w_valve_reftest;
Delete from w_valve_reftest a
where rowid> (select min(rowid)
from w_valve_reftest b where b.xfmid_value=a.XFMID_VALUE);
Select count(*) from w_valve_reftest;
```

Next I want to update the target.reference_1 with the value from source.ref1_value and target.reference_2 with source.ref2_value where source.xfmid_value=target.xfm_id

Here is what I have, but for some reason it is updating 17,000+ records. Rather than the 93 I expect.

```
update w_isolationvalve
set w_isolationvalve.reference_1=(select ref1_value from w_valve_reftest where w_isolationvalve.xfm_id=w_valve_reftest.xfmid_value);

update W_isolationvalve
set w_isolationvalve.reference_2=(select ref2_value from w_valve_reftest where w_isolationvalve.xfm_id=w_valve_reftest.xfmid_value);
```

I'm no expert, but not a rookie any longer. I've hacked it this far using google. Thanks for any assist.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query should be:

```
update a
set reference_1=b.ref1_value,
refrence_2=b.ref2_value 
FROM w_isolationvalve a
JOIN w_valve_reftest b ON a.xfm_id=b.xfmid_value
```

As for the update counts, it will only be 93 only if xfm_id and xfmid_value are unique.

Also be careful of non-deterministic updates.
If your select will have multiple results for your join condition, the update will be executed once for each of the multiple results and you will not know what you end up with.

This should work in Oracle:

```
MERGE INTO w_isolationvalve  a
USING
(
SELECT * FROM w_valve_reftest 
)b
ON(a.xfm_id = b.xfmid_value)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
a.reference_1 = b.ref1_value,
a.refrence_2 = b.ref2_value ;
```

Since you do not like merge. I think this should also work in Oracle:

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT a.reference_1, a.refrence_2, b.ref1_value , b.ref2_value
 FROM w_isolationvalve  a
 INNER JOIN w_valve_reftest b
 ON a.xfm_id = b.xfmid_value
) t
SET t.reference_1  = t.ref1_value ,
t.refrence_2 =t.ref2_value
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriel - I get a command not ended properly error so I'm thinking some ()'s or a ; needed, but still erroring. I did a cut and paste - and I caught refrence typo.update a
set reference_1=b.ref1_value,
reference_2=b.ref2_value 
FROM w_isolationvalve a
JOIN w_valve_reftest b ON a.xfm_id=xfmid_value

Comment: Also what DBMS are you using ? Note that I made an edit quicly after answering and it should be a.xfm_id=b.xfmid_value


As a tip, if you populate a https://dbfiddle.uk/ with your database type, table structure and sample data and ask here about your expected result. People will be more likely to jump and help you :)

Comment: Oracle - using sqldeveloper - cut and paste still produces SQL not properly ended. Thanks for the dbfiddle hint, If I'm using it right - the same error there.

Comment: I've update my answer with syntax that should work on Oracle. Please paste your dbfiddle link if you still have issues.

Comment: Can this be accomplished using update and not merge. My test data merge works find. It does not work in production where the target table is part of a larger transaction that perhaps doesn't like MERGE.

Comment: try the second version I added